# How can I search through multiple worksheets in a excel file for a value and add its results?

Tags: vba, excel

I have around 20 worksheets in a spreadsheet titled by date... 1.2.2015, 1.4.2015, 1.6.2015, etc. I want to search each worksheet according to the date for a particular word (there will be about 6 different words....Brotherhood, Youth, etc). When that word is found I want to add the values for the matching word.

```
        A              B       C

      1/2/2015

5     Brotherhood    2.00     5.00 

6     Brotherhood    10.00    5.00 

7     Brotherhood             5.00 

8     Youth          1.00     5.00 

9     Brotherhood             10.00 

10    Brotherhood    5.00     1.00
```

So, if I referenced date 1/2/2015 and looked for "Brotherhood" it would go to worksheet '1.2.2015' search for "Brotherhood" and return the sum of the third column. The result should equal 26.00.

This is a formula I was working on but it doesn't do everything I want and I will have to manually have to change it for each calender date I want to reference. Also, it doesn't always add correctly.

```
IFERROR(SUM(VLOOKUP($D$1,'1.2.2015'!$A$5:$C$10,3)*'1.2.2015'!$C$5:$C$10*('1.2.2015'!$A$5:$A$10=$D$1)),0)
```

D1 would be filled in with the word Brotherhood.

Is there a easier way to accomplish this? And can someone tell me why my formula doesn't always work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SumIfs` intead, it's simpler i guess :
`=SUMIFS(C1:C6,A1:A6,D1)`

Then you can use this formula to loop through all worksheets. Using method
`For each ws in worksheets ... next ws`
Note : You will probably have to check the name of the worksheet, so that you accidentaly don't count cells on sheets you don't want to count.

I presume you will have to determine last row on each worksheet. You can use
`intLastRow = ws.cells(ws.rows.count,3).end(xlUp).row`
Note : Presuming there is nothing below the range we are adding.

To count total use an incremental line in your code
`dblSumTotal = dblSumTotal + Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(ws.range("C1:C" & intLastRow ), ws.range("A1:A" & intLastRow ) ,"Brotherhood")`
Note : Instead of string *"Brotherhood"* you can of course use a cell reference.

Comment: I don't know how to add code... I changed my formula to sumif but I haven't figured out how to check all worksheets to compare

Comment: @oldbutnew [Databison - VBA For Loop – For Next and For Each In Next](http://www.databison.com/vba-for-loop-for-next-and-for-each-in-next/).Other link [MSDN - For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264596.aspx)